# Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<website.Class1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<library.Class1>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, generics, edmx

I'm using MVC on .net 4.5.

I have separated models from website into a class library, and have tt class file of .edmx replicated to my website so i can access model classes.

Though when I return some data from library like this,

```
List<website.Class1> a = objLibraryRef.GetFileLists1();
```

i get this error.

```
Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<website.Class1>'
to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<library.Class1>'
```

I don't want to reference to class library for accessing model classes.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks & Cheers.

Comment: I guess `objLibraryRef.GetFileLists1()` retruns `System.Collections.Generic.List<library.Class1>`

Comment: What is the return type of the method? it should be `List<website.Class1>`

Comment: no. it is `List<library.Class1>`, how can it be `List<website.Class1>`

Comment: Yes. It is @AlexeyNis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the `library.Class1` to `website.Class1`. Even if they have same name the classes are different because they are in separate libraries.

```
List<website.Class1> a = objLibraryRef.GetFileLists1()
                         .Select(c => new website.Class1 {
                                   property1 = c.property1,
                                   ...
                                   propertyN = c.propertyN
                          }).ToList();
```

**Note:** Replace `property1..N` with your properties (i.e. `Name`). For this you **don't have to reference** the library where `library.Class1` is created.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya The OP don't want to add reference to `library.Class1`. To make a `Select` over a class that you didn't include it's library, is possible :).

Comment: @JenishRabadiya You really made me think that won't work, so I made a project and tested it, result: *It works flawless*.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly, Just wanted to know does it have any processing overhead or performance issue?

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh This have a complexity `O(n)` because will iterate through all items. The performance really depends on the number of the items, also, over performanace there are other benefits. But, if you filter them before mapping (`objLibraryRef.GetFileLists1().Where(someCondition)`), you can save some time.

Answer (score 2):

Your DAL method is returning `List<T>` of type `Class1` which is in `library` namespace while you are assigning it to of type `Class1` but its namespace is different which is `website1` not `library`.

You can use implicit type variable which will infer the type which is returned by DAL library method:

```
var list = objLibraryRef.GetFileLists1();
```

Or if you reall want List of type `website.Class1` then you have to project on the List again as @adricadar suggested in his post.

Comment: Yes, Exactly. But i replicated tt file, So my class1 definition matches in website as well as service, still it's showing error

Comment: you are right, but namespace is different so you cannot assign it directly

Comment: Ok, If i take it as `var`, can i do model binding to my view with it?

Comment: you can bind in view, if in view your model is ``List<library.Class1>`` not ``List<website.Class1>``

Comment: Means either i will have to reference to `library` for model class or project on list like adricadar suggested ?

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh How I sugested you don't have to reference `library`. you will convert `library.Class1` to `website.Class1`, no reference to `library` is needed.

Comment: Yes, As I don't have to reference `library`, I will go with adricadar solution, Thanks for your efforts @EhsanSajjad

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map those two objects. Even if your definition matches they are two different classes and you can not just directly convert those. [Here](https://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists%20and%20Arrays) is an example of how to map lists.

Comment: That's good solution to, I will give it a try after some time.